# gtk PrintSettings default values?

Tags: gtk, pygtk

How can I get default print values (default printer, paper size), BEFORE running PrintOperation.run() ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is not possible. Only way is to set up PrintSettings and PageSetup in advance and create a new PrintOperation for each call to run, and save PrintSettings after each of them.

Answer (score -1):

Is it this you are looking for ?

http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkprintsettings.html

Comment: No. This is an empty object, I need it populated with default values.